Sudden Unresponsiveness in Linux System After Inactivity
My Linux system doesn't respond a few minutes after inactive.
It does not respond to keyboard press, mouse click and monitor does not detect (I have tried with other keyboard, mouse and monitor as well).
It does not respond even when I press the power button.
I had to turn off the power switch and resume the power only the system is functioning.
Any idea what is happening with the CPU? XD
These are the part of the log messages I managed to trace back after the system was inactive.
journalctl -o short-iso  | grep "^2024-05.*error*"

2024-05-19T12:00:35+0800 dell gnome-shell[27687]: Exiting due to channel error.
2024-05-19T12:00:35+0800 dell gnome-shell[26989]: Exiting due to channel error.
2024-05-19T12:00:35+0800 dell gnome-shell[27079]: Exiting due to channel error.
2024-05-19T12:00:35+0800 dell gnome-shell[26302]: Exiting due to channel error.
2024-05-19T12:11:39+0800 dell systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled (file watch) being skipped.
2024-05-19T12:11:46+0800 dell thermald[1010]: error: could not parse file /etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml
2024-05-19T12:11:46+0800 dell thermald[1010]: error: could not parse file /etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml
2024-05-19T12:11:46+0800 dell thermald[1010]: error: could not parse file /etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml
2024-05-19T12:12:00+0800 dell /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1409]:         (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
2024-05-19T12:12:06+0800 dell canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd[1148]: Task "refresh" returned an error: livepatch check failed: POST request to "https://livepatch.canonical.com/v1/client/2c7e4cdff9da43bb85f27e95cb4e2051/updates" failed, retrying in 30s.
2024-05-19T12:12:07+0800 dell goa-daemon[1454]: /org/gnome/OnlineAccounts/Accounts/account_1649926201_1: Setting AttentionNeeded to TRUE because EnsureCredentials() failed with: No credentials found in the keyring (goa-error-quark, 4)
2024-05-19T12:12:27+0800 dell snapd[1007]: stateengine.go:149: state ensure error: persistent network error: Get "https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/sections": dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
2024-05-19T12:12:36+0800 dell canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd[1148]: Task "refresh" returned an error: livepatch check failed: POST request to "https://livepatch.canonical.com/v1/client/2c7e4cdff9da43bb85f27e95cb4e2051/updates" failed, retrying in 1m0s.
2024-05-19T12:12:59+0800 dell snap-store[1976]: not handling error no-network for action refresh: Cannot refresh cache whilst offline
2024-05-19T12:13:31+0800 dell snap-store[1976]: not GsPlugin error snapd-error-quark:10: status-code=500 kind=(null) message=persistent network error: Get "https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/sections": dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
2024-05-19T12:13:31+0800 dell snap-store[1976]: not handling error failed for action get-categories: status-code=500 kind=(null) message=persistent network error: Get "https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/sections": dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
2024-05-19T12:13:31+0800 dell snap-store[1976]: not handling error failed for action get-popular: persistent network error: Get "https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/find?architecture=amd64&category=featured&confinement=strict%2Cclassic&fields=base%2Cconfinement%2Clinks%2Ccontact%2Cdescription%2Cdownload%2Clicense%2Cprices%2Cprivate%2Cpublisher%2Crevision%2Csummary%2Ctitle%2Ctype%2Cversion%2Cwebsite%2Cstore-url%2Cmedia%2Ccommon-ids%2Ccategories%2Cchannel": dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
2024-05-19T12:13:36+0800 dell canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd[1148]: Task "refresh" returned an error: livepatch check failed: POST request to "https://livepatch.canonical.com/v1/client/2c7e4cdff9da43bb85f27e95cb4e2051/updates" failed, retrying in 1m30s.
2024-05-19T12:14:05+0800 dell snap-store[1976]: Failed to find refreshable snaps: status-code=500 kind=(null) message=cannot list updates: persistent network error: Post "https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh": dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
2024-05-19T12:15:06+0800 dell canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd[1148]: Task "refresh" returned an error: livepatch check failed: POST request to "https://livepatch.canonical.com/v1/client/2c7e4cdff9da43bb85f27e95cb4e2051/updates" failed, retrying in 2m0s.
2024-05-19T12:17:06+0800 dell canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd[1148]: Task "refresh" returned an error: livepatch check failed: POST request to "https://livepatch.canonical.com/v1/client/2c7e4cdff9da43bb85f27e95cb4e2051/updates" failed, retrying in 2m30s.
2024-05-19T12:17:06+0800 dell canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd[1148]: Task "refresh" retries exhausted with error: livepatch check failed: POST request to "https://livepatch.canonical.com/v1/client/2c7e4cdff9da43bb85f27e95cb4e2051/updates" failed.
2024-05-19T12:19:19+0800 dell snapd[33326]: stateengine.go:149: state ensure error: decode new commands catalog: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout or context cancellation while reading body)
2024-05-19T12:20:07+0800 dell snap-store[1976]: not handling error download-failed for action refresh: E: Release file for https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/focal-cran40/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 1d 8h 53min 2s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
2024-05-19T12:20:14+0800 dell snap-store[1976]: not handling error failed for action refresh: E: Release file for https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/focal-cran40/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 1d 8h 52min 45s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
2024-05-19T12:28:18+0800 dell dbus-daemon[970]: [system] Rejected send message, 0 matched rules; type="error", sender=":1.84" (uid=1000 pid=5144 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo" label="unconfined") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.5" (uid=0 pid=967 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="unconfined")
2024-05-19T12:28:18+0800 dell dbus-daemon[970]: [system] Rejected send message, 0 matched rules; type="error", sender=":1.84" (uid=1000 pid=5144 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo" label="unconfined") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.5" (uid=0 pid=967 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="unconfined")

Any help will be greatly appreciated! 
